# How to overlay an RGBA image on top of an RGB using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mask

I have two images (`CV_8UC3`) and a mask (`CV_8UC1`) all of the same size and I would like to apply the mask to one of the images and put it on top of the other:

```js
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

const bg = cv.imread('./bg.jpg').cvtColor(cv.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
//Loading the foreground image in RGB
const fg = cv.imread('./fg.jpg');
//Generating the mask with only one channel
const mask = cv.imread('./mask.jpg').cvtColor(cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

const fgChannels = fg.split();
fgChannels.push(mask);
const maskedFg = new cv.Mat(fgChannels);

const output = cv.addWeighted(bg, 1, maskedFg, 1, 0).cvtColor(cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
cv.imwrite('./output.jpg', output);
```

And here how it works. First the `bg.jpg` file:

[image]

Then the `fg.jpg` file:

[image]

The `mask.jpg` file:

[image]

And finally, the `output.jpg` file:

[image]

My problem with the output is that I was not expecting to see any part of the background image unless they are underneath the tunnel's opening. Can someone please help me find the solution?

Comment: Also the first image parts seem transparent, is that a problem too?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm not sure what exactly you mean. But all 3 input images are JPEGs and as a result, they don't have an alpha channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, OpenCV does not have a function to do this directly. Instead, you have to use a combination of functions to do it:

```js
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

const bg = cv.imread('./bg.jpg').convertTo(cv.CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255);
const fg = cv.imread('./fg.jpg').convertTo(cv.CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255);
const mask = cv.imread('./mask.jpg').convertTo(cv.CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255);
const allOnes = new cv.Mat(mask.rows, mask.cols, cv.CV_32FC3, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

const invMask = allOnes.sub(mask);
const output = mask.hMul(fg).add(invMask.hMul(bg));
cv.imwrite('./output.jpg', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Only add the masked part from bg to fg or remove the masked part on fg before that?
I don't think you are applying the mask correctly.

The following approach should work to apply the mask:

- If the mask is binary: use bitwise_and with bg and mask
- If the mask needs to be grayscale: use element-wise multiplication

The resulting masked_bg will only contain the masked part of the image.
Also note that output.jpg is too bright because you are simply adding the two images on top of each other. You could change the weights to 0.5 each or make sure the colored parts of both images never overlap.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the second solution a bit more? Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: No, if you understand the concept you should easily be able to write the code yourself. Basically, every pixels brightness is set according to the corresponding mask pixel value. 0 = black, 255 = full brightness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Hadamard%20product,of%20the%20original%20two%20matrices. Docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a385c09827713dc3e6d713bfad8460706